# Replace <div> with php contents using javascript (no jQuery) based on the browser viewport

Tags: php, javascript, function, viewport

Hi I am very new to JavaScript. With the help of some friends around I was able to compile this code below. However I am not able to connect them all together.

**Mission:**
I want to replace the `<div>` in my `index.php` with corresponding php code in respective files based on the viewport.

1. Generalize the function `getAsides()` for use with multiple files and divs.
2. Once visitor changes browser size, Automatically page must be reloaded.
3. The entire code must be compatible with IE6 too. (this is a mandate) Currently my function `getAsides()` is compatible with IE6.

**Code I have:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAsides(){
    document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML="<img src='loadingImage.gif'>";
    var x = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var x = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    } else {
        // @TODO Fallback
    }
    x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", true);
    x.send("");
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(x.readyState == 4) {
            if(x.status==200) 
                document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = x.responseText;
            else 
                document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = "Error loading document";
        }
    }
} 

function getViewport() {
    var 
    x=window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.getElementsByTagName.clientWidth,
    y=window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.getElementsByTagName.clientHeight;

    if (x >=960 && x<=1200) {

    // Here using the function ' function getAsides()' I want to replace
    //'<div id='aside'></div>' with 'aside.php'

    } else if (x >=1201 && x<=1600) {

    // Here using the function ' function getAsides()' I want to replace 
    //'<div id='aside'></div>' with 'aside.php' and
    //'<div id='aside_medium'></div>' with 'aside_medium.php'

    } else if (x >=1600) {

    // Here using the function ' function getAsides()' I want to replace  
    //'<div id='aside'></div>' with 'aside.php' and
    //'<div id='aside_medium'></div>' with 'aside_medium.php' and
    //'<div id='aside_large'></div>' with 'aside_large.php'
    }
}

if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready, false);
    window.addEventListener('load', ready, false);
} else if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', ready);
}

window.onresize = function() {
    reloadPage(self.innerWidth);
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="aside"></div>
    <div id="aside_medium"></div>
    <div id="aside_large"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Questions:**

1. Am I on the right track? Is there a better way of doing this? If yes then how?
2. What should be the correct code / syntax to achieve what is mentioned in the **'Mission'**

**Special notes:**

I am not going to use jQuery or any other JavaScript libraries because this is the only JavaScript in my template and I do not want to slowdown my page speed / performance as that is the key factor for this template.

Comment: Just to be sure - you have to load those divs using xhttp and reload whole page after user changes the browser's window size, right? I'm just wondering what do you want to achieve/how your application is going to work. If that code is used only to make the page look different on different window sizes then maybe you should try css3 media queries and polyfills for IE6-8, eg: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: Ok, I get it. I think that reloading whole page on window.resize is not a good idea. In this scenario I would only load content if the window gets bigger and hide content (using media queries) when the window gets smaller. If somebody decreases the size of the screen we do not have to remove the content and when he grows it again we do not have to fetch it from the server. Btw: respond.js does not depend on jQuery, only on one small polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

A function can be written in thousand different ways and there is no one correct way to write one. Your question might in fact solicit opinion, debate or extended discussion, not really fitting into stackowerflow's Q&A format. That being said, there is some room for improvement to your code.

1. Consider congesting your cross-browser XMLHttpRequest check. Like so:

   `var x = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : (XMLHttpRequest && new XMLHttpRequest()) || null;`
2. Move your code to an external js file. It's always never a good idea to have inline javascript.

Comment: Well eventually with final code I would do the splitting into respective files. I just mentioned it here for the ease.